# Reason of Flutter error: SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Failed to start accept), address = localhost, port = xxxx

Tags: flutter

When I Run `flutter run -d chrome` command *([ref](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web#create-a-new-project-with-web-support))*, get the **Failed to start accept** error:

```
SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Failed to start accept), address = localhost, port = 6670
```

Additional info:

```
flutter channel => beta
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: after flutter upgrade, i am facing the same issue now.

Comment: i find a wordaround, just restart your pc. the issue maybe caused by chrome debug session process hang.

Comment: Im actually waiting for any update for this since its also my issue

Answer (score 8):

OK, this is also my issue and I manage to find a workaround

1. on cmd run "ipconfig"
2. after running the "ipconfig" get the value of IPv4 Address.
3. then on the app run:

   ```
   flutter run -d chrome --web-port=8080 --web-hostname= *the value of IPv4 Address*
   ```

Comment: Yes, that's what happened when I tried it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Network LAN Properties -> Deselect the IPv6 Connectivity -> Click Ok.
Its Works for me.

Comment: What do you mean about "Network LAN Properties"? Can you change in a more specific description?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just had installed the `release` app, which has different signature, I guess, so I just had to uninstall it from the emulator, then debug and everything worked out just fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Internet permission

The issue has to do with the app's "Capabilities". You need to allow "Outgoing Connections (Client)".

The `.entitlements` file should have this:

```xml
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
```

For AndroidManifest.xml it is:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Here's in Xcode:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Go to your PowerShell run as administer run following commond**

1.net stop hns

2.net start hns

Comment: unclear what this is supposed to mean and how it is related